# How to correctly size hierarchical data

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have been trying to learn d3.js for a project. The data I want to display is of the form:

```
var data = [{
    "name": "parent",
        "top": ["t1", "t2"],
        "bottom": [{
        "upper": "u1",
            "lower": "l1"
    }, {
        "upper": "u2",
            "lower": "l2"
    }]
}];
```

with arbitrarily long arrays. I would like to display the data like so:

```
 -----------------
| name 
|      -----------
|     | t1  
|     |-----------
|     | t2
|     |-----------
|     | u1
|     |-----------
|     | u2
|      -----------
 -----------------
       -----------
      | l2      
      |-----------
      | l1
       -----------
```

I need to pack this data as tightly as possible automatically. Also notice that I need the "l" elements in reversed order. So my questions are:

1. How should I position the "u" elements directly below the "t" elements?
2. How should I determine the size of the box surrounding the parent, based on the "t" and "u" elements?
3. How should I position the "l" elements directly below the parent box, in reverse order?

Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/p3wg0L8v/

Code reposted if you can't get to jsfiddle:

```
var data = [{
    "name": "parent",
        "top": ["t1", "t2"],
        "bottom": [{
        "upper": "u1",
            "lower": "l1"
    }, {
        "upper": "u2",
            "lower": "l2"
    }]
}];

var textSpacing = 16;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 480).attr("height", 160);

var parents = svg.selectAll("g").data(data).enter();

var parent = parents.append("g");

parent.append("text").text(function (d) {
    return d.name;
}).attr("x", textSpacing).attr("y", textSpacing);

parent.append("rect").attr("x", 0).attr("y", 0).attr("width", 400).attr("height", 90).attr("fill", "none").attr("stroke", "black").attr("stroke-width", 1);

var top = parent.selectAll("text.top").data(function (d) {
    return d.top;
}).enter().append("text").attr("class", "top").attr("x", 60).attr("y", function (d, i) {
    return textSpacing * (i + 2);
}).text(function (d) {
    return d;
});

var bottom = parent.selectAll("g").data(function (d) {
    return d.bottom
}).enter().append("g");

bottom.append("text").attr("x", 60).attr("y", function (d, i) {
    return textSpacing * (i + 4);
}).text(function (d) {
    return d.upper;
});

bottom.append("text").attr("x", 60).attr("y", function (d, i) {
    return textSpacing * (8 - i);
}).text(function (d) {
    return d.lower;
});
```

Right now I am basically hard-coding the lengths of the arrays, but I need to be able to handle various sizes, as there will be many "parent" objects.

Comment: Can your hierarchy ever be deeper than your example, or will you always have a root node with a top and a bottom attribute, with top and bottom both arrays?

Comment: i.e. can the objects in bottom have children?

Comment: @ckersch the bottom objects will not contain arrays, they will be of a known size.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the sizes of your `bottom` and `top` arrays and add them together to get a total size for each `parent` object.

Adding the sizes of each parent object together will give you a total size for all of the objects in `data`. You can then use that size to assign a total size to everything.

EDIT:
For positioning everything, once you have the sizes of each bottom, top, and parent, you can position parent `g` elements with the `transform` attribute:

```
.attr('transform',function(d){
    return 'translate(' + xPosition + ',' + yPosition + ')'
});
```

Then position bottoms and tops as `g` elements relative to the parents, again using the `transform` attribute to locate each bottom or top relative to its parent. (Set the first element equal to the x-attribute and the second equal to 0 for tops and the height of the corresponding top for bottoms)

Finally, when you append uppers and lowers to the bottom, you can append them it two groups, set a `transform` to move all of the lowers down by the height of all of the uppers, and finally position the `text` elements based only on their position in the lowest level of the array, since the `transform`s that you've put on the `g` elements for parent, bottom, and upper (or whatever the ancestors of the text node are) will determine it's position in the hierarchy.

Essentially, use transforms on the `g` elements to build the positions for large blocks of the hierarchy and then only use the `y` attribute to position an element relative to its siblings in the hierarchy.

Comment: Okay, I think that answers part 2, how to size the parent component. So I will set the height of each parent using `attr("height", function (d) { return textSpacing * (d.top.length + d.bottom.length + 1.5); })`. How can I position the elements below the parent?

Comment: You can use the `transform` attribute to move the parent where you want it, and then use more `transform`s to move groups relative to the parent. I've edited my answer to explain this a bit better.